# Single context type, multiple providers

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

How do I setup and configure Entity Framework Core to use a single `DbContext` class and manage migrations for multiple providers (SQL Server, Sqlite)?

I have in production, a .NET 6 Blazor WASM project hosted in an ASP.NET Web API using the standard architecture of C# projects (client, API, logic, data, and shared projects). `DbContext` is injected into the repository and then used in the logic layer. Once the request is complete, the service is disposed as well as the `DbContext`. All good and well.

I want to create a companioning desktop app (WinUi 3) that utilizes the same Logic and data layer, but using an SQLite data provider. I could use a new `DbContext` class that inherits from existing `DbContext`, but then repository doesn't know which `DbContext` to use.

[Documentation (for multiple providers and single context)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#using-one-context-type) doesn't give me a new `ModelSnapshot` for the SQLite provider. Hence, the SQL code generated to `update-database` is still written in the syntax for SQL Server.

Architecture and configuration :

[image]

`Data.Migrations.csproj` (project only used for migrations as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)) :

- Migrations (folder for SQL Server provider)
- Migrations/Sqlite (folder for SQLite provider)

`Data.csproj` (project with `DbContext` and repository) :

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    protected readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

    public Context() { }

    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // some model configuration
    }

    // DbSets...
}

public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    // some interface methods
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private DbSet<T> entities;

    public Repository()
    {
    }

    // implement some interface methods
}

public class DbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<Context>
{
    public Context CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>();

        if (DbContextHelper.Provider == "SqlServer")
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(DbContextHelper.ConnectionString,
                    x => x.MigrationsAssembly("Data.Migrations"));
        else if (DbContextHelper.Provider == "Sqlite")
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(DbContextHelper.ConnectionString,
                    x => x.MigrationsAssembly("Data.Migrations"));
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Database provider not specified");

        return new Context(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

`Logic.csproj`:

```
public interface ICustomerService
{
    // some interface methods
}

public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{
    protected readonly IRepository<Customer> _customerRepository;

    public CustomerService(IRepository<Customer> customerRepository)
    {
        _customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    // implement some interface methods
}
```

`Api.csproj`:

```
// Program class

builder.Services.AddDbContext<Context>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Context"),
    x => x.MigrationsAssembly("Data.Migrations"))
);

builder.Services.AddTransient<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();

builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
builder.Services.AddScoped<DbContext, Context>();
```

`WinUi.csproj` (WinUi 3 app ~= UWP app):

```
// App.xaml.cs

public App()
{
    services.AddDbContext<InSpecContext, Context>(options =>
        options.UseSqlite(DbContextHelper.ConnectionString,
        x => x.MigrationsAssembly("Data.Migrations"))
    );
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248578/discussion-between-a-dixon-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: Did this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) help you?

Comment: @XinranShen; I think so, haven't fully finished testing my scenario. The part that wasn't clear in the documentation, is that you need a separate "Migrations" project for each provider (ie: Data.SqlServer, Data.Sqlite). But after getting those setup, I am able to manage migrations for each provider independently while using a single Context class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting rid of the repository pattern as suggested by the now deleted comments made by @PanagiotisKanavos.

Then I made a separate migrations project for each of my providers with the DbContext file located in the `Data` project.

Then in the `Logic` services, instead of injecting the generic repository or the DbContext, I am injecting `IDbContextFactory<MyContext> factory` as suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor)

The configuration for the API looks like this

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<Context>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Context"),
    x => x.MigrationsAssembly("Data.SqlServer"))
);
```

The configuration for the WinUi app looks like this:

```cs
services.AddDbContextFactory<Context>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite(DbContextHelper.ConnectionString,
    x => x.MigrationsAssembly("Data.Sqlite"))
);
```

[image: Projects]